# No default engine was specified and no extension was provided (expressJS & jade)

Tags: node.js, express, pug

This is my (simplified) `app.coffee`:

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/app/views')
app.set('view enigne', 'jade')

app.listen 8000
```

However, when I visit my app in the browser I get the following error message:

```
Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided
```

**Edit**: Turns out I'm an idiot and spelled "engine" incorrectly. Thanks to @lascort for pointing it out!

Comment: You have a simple typo, did you try debugging this yourself by comparing it against working examples before asking about it here?

Comment: I literally spent an hour trying to figure out what was wrong. Sometimes you just need fresh eyes I guess.

Comment: I typo a lot, if you have code that "looks" great. Check you spelling. I often take this a step further and copy/paste certain words that "look" right from a source that is working.

Comment: I think the correct response here is, "lol". ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
app.set('view >>enigne<<', 'jade')
```